# change UI wait 2000 milliseconds and change UI again

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I want to show some text and a picture In a way that text will be visible for 2 seconds, and then the picture will replace it.
Also in that time not to make the UI to be stuck.

I tried the following:
In WPF UI:

```
            <Border x:Name="ComparisonResultImageBox" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Background="White" Margin="8,5,8,5">
                <Image x:Name="DiffrenceImage"></Image>
            </Border>
```

AND:

```
            <Border x:Name="LoadingComparisonResultLabel" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Background="White" Margin="0,5,8,5">
                <Label Content="Loading Comparison Result..." FontFamily="Open Sans" FontSize="13" ></Label>
            </Border>
```

Then in the code,  when some button on the page get clicked I invoked the following method:

```
private void ClearComparePicture() {
    DiffrenceImage.Source = null;

    LoadingComparisonResultLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    ComparisonResultImageBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    DiffrenceImage.Source = newBitmapImage;

    LoadingComparisonResultLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    ComparisonResultImageBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

**The problem is that the text doesn't show during the sleep time....**

Comment: Basics of GUI programming, hanging the UI thread with a Sleep() will prevent it from doing any UI related task.  Like updating the text on the screen.  Use a DispatcherTimer or async code with Task.Delay() instead..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use any blocking calls (long running synchronous) on the UI thread.

The simplest change that might make this work is to use an `async Task` or `async void`.

```
private async Task ClearComparePicture() {
    DiffrenceImage.Source = null;    

    LoadingComparisonResultLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    ComparisonResultImageBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    await Task.Delay(2000);
    DiffrenceImage.Source = newBitmapImage;

    LoadingComparisonResultLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    ComparisonResultImageBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```